# Implementation of ActionMode.Callback

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-actionmode

I have an Implementation of ActionMode to display the number of multi 
selected items in a RecyclerView.

I would like to know when the back button in the actionMode is tapped so as to correspondingly reset the recyclerView but while implementing the ActionMode.Callback, i noticed that onDestroyActionMode is called whenever ActionMode is updated thus `actionMode?.setTitle($selectedItems.size)`, which makes it impossible reset the recyclerView - remove selected items, remove overlay color and notify the recyclerview of data set changed.
[image: Mulltiselection]

Here's my Callback

```
inner class ActionModeCallback : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item?.getItemId()) {
            R.id.action_delete -> {
                myAdapter?.deleteSelectedIds()
                actionMode?.setTitle("") //remove item count from action mode.
                actionMode?.finish()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = mode?.getMenuInflater()
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.action_mode_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menu?.findItem(R.id.action_delete)?.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyActionMode Called")
        //myAdapter?.selectedIds?.clear()
        //myAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        actionMode = null
    }
}
```

**How Can i know when the ActionMode back button is tapped?**
Full source code Here =>https://github.com/Edge-Developer/RecyclerViewMultiSelectExample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holy Gosh. It was my fault, i was starting a New ActionMode each time an item is selected (through an interface on MainActivity) instead of checking if it has already been started before starting a new One.

Here was my code

```
actionMode = startActionMode(ActionModeCallback())
```

Here is the updated code

```
if (actionMode == null) actionMode = startActionMode(ActionModeCallback())
```

now, the onDestroyActionMode is called only once, after the actionMode is dismissed!

You can check [the github repo](https://github.com/Edge-Developer/RecyclerViewMultiSelectExample) on how's it was implemented

This problem was faced while [implementing multiselection on a recyclerView](https://edgedevstudio.com/recyclerview-item-multi-select-tutorial/).

Comment: What is the use of `onPrepareActionMode`? When it is called and what should we generally do there. I have gone through the docs but didn't get it right.